# Accessing the data field in a pcap dump file in python

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap

I am using the following code:

```
import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('/home/my_location/python_parse/my_file.pcap')
count = 0;
for caps in cap:
    print caps.pretty_print();
    print "Count is " + str(count)
    count+=1;
```

My pcapfile is located here [https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj1_HY10QdBTa5zNMcZadSK3qAM](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=20149795003133150377)
If someone has any alternative hosting site, I am ready to put it up at that location also.

I am unable to access the data field using pyshark. When I open up the pcap file in wireshark , I can see the data in this field:
[image]

Can anyone offer any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `usb_capdata` field of the DATA layer.

```
import pyshark
caps = pyshark.FileCapture('/home/my_location/python_pars/my_file.pcap')
print caps[10].layers[1].usb_capdata
```

Will output the same as wireshark :

```
'80:08:0b:82:00:00:85:97:8a:86:00:00'
```